# git commit --author doesn't work when global not set

Tags: git

working on a lab machine which has a shared login.  don't want to set global git config parameters.

```
git commit --author="username <email>"
```

This used to work on older git versions. now it produces this error:

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'blah@blah.(none)')
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What are you entering for `--author`?

Comment: "name <name@host.com>"

Comment: Is that _literally_ what you're entering? The `--author` flag still works, and will accept a string in that format.

Comment: added a junk config, --author works properly when git config was set.  It apparently doesn't if git config has never been run.

Comment: `git commit` will still accept the `--author` flag even if `~/.gitconfig` does not exist.

Comment: With git 2.17.1, @richmb is correct.  You need to run git config with some bogus data before the `--author` flag will work.  Sounds like this is fixed in git 2.29.

Comment: This has not been fixed, `--author` still doesn't work in git 2.30.2

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What if you set the git config info just for the current repository?

```
  git config user.email "you@example.com"
  git config user.name "Your Name"
```

**EDIT**
Based on OP comment a possible solution is:

```
GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="you@email.com" && GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="Your Name" && git commit
```

Comment: Other people use the machine and the same repo. I guess I could set up the git config and then remove the configuration when I'm done.

Comment: @richmb I've edited the answer to maybe a best solution for you scenario

Comment: You do not need the `&&` between variable definitions.  Not even `dash` requires them.

Comment: I had the same issue and got it to work with git 2.17.1 by issuing `git config user.email "bogus@url.com"` and `git config user.name "Bogus"`  Until I did that, it would not accept any `author=`, after that, the same command with `author=` worked and the author's name is not Bogus.

Comment: thanks, it worked

Comment: Does not work for me. The environment variables must have changed.

Answer (score 11):

Another solution is, to set the identity just for one run of `git commit` and make use of the `-c` option of `git`.

```
git -c user.name="Your Name" -c user.email="you@example.com" commit -m "message"
```

My scenario is to run a docker container where I'm a user (not being root) in the container, which has no write permission on its home directory. The image is `docker.io/alpine/git`.

```
$ docker run -u 1004:1005 -it --rm --entrypoint=/bin/sh docker.io/alpine/git 
~ $ git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
error: could not lock config file /git/.gitconfig: Permission denied
```

Comment: The only one that worked for me

Answer (score 5):

First, With Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), the error message is clearer.

See [commit 9ed104e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9ed104e5cacdc44f2fe7c2b1fdeada94622ca4e9) (21 Aug 2020) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e9bd00a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e9bd00ab2dad0148c8643a773ea2e68d624f5624), 31 Aug 2020)</sup>

> ### [`ident`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9ed104e5cacdc44f2fe7c2b1fdeada94622ca4e9): say whose identity is missing when giving `user.name` hint

> If `user.name` and `user.email` have not been configured and the user invokes:
>
> ```
> git commit --author=...
> ```
>
> without specifying the committer identity, then Git errors out with a message asking the user to configure `user.name` and `user.email` but doesn't tell the user which attribution was missing.
>
> This can be confusing for a user new to Git who isn't aware of the distinction between user, author, and committer.
>
> Give such users a bit more help by extending the error message to also say which attribution is expected.

The error message will clearly state:

```
Author identity unknown
# or
Committer identity unknown
```

Second, from [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29685337/git-commit-author-doesnt-work-when-global-not-set#comment47507897_29685405):

> Other people use the machine and the same repo. I guess I could set up the git config and then remove the configuration when I'm done

You can wrap the git command and forcing each used to identify themselves (once per shell session).
See "[Best pracitces for multi-developer Git for single user application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63555737/6309)" and my project [**`VonC/gitw`**](https://github.com/VonC/gitw).

Answer (score 4):

In Terminal:

- `git config --global user.email "nive54@gmail.com"`
- `git config --global user.name "Nivetha"`

Note:

> GitHub registered email --> `nive54@gmail.com`
>
> Your system name --> `Nivetha` (Refer to `thispc->properties` for this.)

Answer (score 1):

You only need to enter your email and username correctly

```
$git config --global user.email "youremail@gmail.com"
$git config --global user.name "yourusername"
```

then, you just commit again. Good luck !!

```
$git commit -m "your commit"
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are working on Gitbash.

The steps include, setting up a username and then providing an email address, so that you can commit the changes, when you use `$git commit -m "message to display"` command.

For username:

```
$git config --global user.name "xyz"
```

For email address:

```
$git config --global user.email anything@gmail.com
```

[Do not use quotes while writing email]

So, the next time you use this command,
`$ git commit -m "abc.txt file added"`
Successful changes are made.